# views_embed_view not working with multiple values argument

Tags: views, 8

I'm trying to embed views like this:

```
 views_embed_view('articles_list', 'block_1', '11+13');
```

If I type 11 in arguments, it does take the argument. It works good if I preview the view and enter '11+13' in "Preview with contextual filters" field... But if I write '11+13' in the views_embed_view() function, it just takes the value of 11. How can I make it work and take both values: 11 and 13?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `views_embed_view` doc comment block:

> - @param ...
>
>   - Any additional parameters will be passed as arguments.

That means any params comes after params `$name` and `$display_id` will consider as contextual filer so you should call `views_embed_view` like:

```
views_embed_view('articles_list', 'block_1', '11', '13');
```

Take a look at [Twig Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_views) Module do the same.